# Is there a way to sort the Questions oldest first?

Tags: support

Is there a way to sort the Questions oldest first, then the newest at the front?

How?

Answer (score 3):

[Yes there is.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

[FEchinger wrote one](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/93574/questions-by-date-backwards)

Comment: Oh, thank you! :)

Comment: If you were asking for the query itself, you could edit your question and I'm sure someone will write the query for you.

Comment: Good idea! (oh, I have to use up characters)

Answer (score 0):

I just found another way: You sort them newest first and then press the button for the last page.

Comment: That gives you the last page ... Which you could also do by just clicking the button for the last page at the bottom of the "newest" list. In fact, it doesn't even do that. It just ignores the page counter if it gets too large.

Comment: that 48357623845763 was ironical - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well, the thing with that irony is that a) it doesn't fly well over the Internet and b) it was plain incorrect in this case.

Comment: Hi @MadTux... You are a funny character... Your profile says you are still 14... Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!! :-)

Comment: I *am* 14, and thank you!